# FBLoginView doesn't work in archive for App Store

Tags: ios

Just applied my first app to Apple, and after about a week, I got a response saying that it didn't pass their QA.

They say that when they press the "Log in" button, i.e FBLoginView I use - nothing happens. They say it's on iPhone 5s with iOS 7.1.1. Now, I've tested the app on iPhone 5s with iOS 7.0 and with iPhone 4s with iOS 7.1.1 - and it worked.

Does anyone know what might be the problem? What can I do?